# Paypal IPN event listener in ASP.NET Web Forms not processing the request properly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, paypal-ipn

Paypal's documentation has instructions for ASP.NET MVC, however in webforms, there is next to no guidance.

Key points, I had to change `HttpRequestBase ipnRequest` to `HttpRequest ipnRequest` because...

> cannot convert from HttpRequestBase to HttpRequest

Which prevented `Request` from working in my code. Which I'm guessing is an issue with my translation from MVC to webforms?

My translation of the working MVC code...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Store the IPN received from PayPal
    LogRequest(Request);

    //Fire and forget verification task
    Task.Run(() => VerifyTask(Request));

    //Reply back a 200 code
    Response.StatusCode = 200;
}
```

This is the MVC version, from Paypal's docs:

```
[HttpPost]
        public HttpStatusCodeResult Receive()
        {
            //Store the IPN received from PayPal
            LogRequest(Request);

            //Fire and forget verification task
            Task.Run(() =>  VerifyTask(Request));

            //Reply back a 200 code
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
```

And this is what the MVC version is executing, and what I'm trying to execute through my webforms translation.

```
private void VerifyTask(HttpRequest ipnRequest) // would be HttpRequestBase following official docs / mvc
{
   var verificationResponse = string.Empty;

    try
    {

        var verificationRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr");

        var Request = HttpContext.Current.Request;

        //Set values for the verification request
        verificationRequest.Method = "POST";
        verificationRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        var param = Request.BinaryRead(ipnRequest.ContentLength);
        strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(param);

        //Add cmd=_notify-validate to the payload
        strRequest = "cmd=_notify-validate&" + strRequest;
        verificationRequest.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;

        //Attach payload to the verification request
        var streamOut = new StreamWriter(verificationRequest.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
        streamOut.Write(strRequest);
        streamOut.Close();

        //Send the request to PayPal and get the response
        var streamIn = new StreamReader(verificationRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        verificationResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
        streamIn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        var hehe = exception;
        //Capture exception for manual investigation
    }

    ProcessVerificationResponse(verificationResponse);
}
```

Using my webforms version, it's failing due to the following:

> HttpContext.Current.Request = 'HttpContext.Current.Request' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'

It feels like I'm failing massively, and not I'm sure if I'm on the right tracks or missing something completely obvious. I understand I haven't been massively clear in the question, my head is very fuzzy and I've been stuck on Paypal Ipn stuff for three days now. If I can add anything which could help any problem solving please comment and I'll do everything I can. Many thanks!

Comment: IPN is a very old service, why are you integrating it in 2020? What specific need to you have of it?

Comment: @PrestonPHX, it's the method I've been taught and most developer friends use. What method would you suggest, and is it easily implemented through ASP.NET webforms? Any resources would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a reliable way to be notified of successful PayPal payments (more reliable and robust than waiting for asynchronous IPN message deliveries), simply capture them directly from your server.

You'll need two new routes, one for 'Set Up Transaction' and one for 'Capture Transaction', [documented here.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/)  If the Checkout-Net-SDK doesn't work for your environment, use direct HTTPS (no SDK) calls to the PayPal REST API.

Once you have those two routes, pair them with this front end: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server